# How do i get my Bitcoin Cash from Mycelium wallet?

Tags: bitcoin-cash, mycelium-wallet

I kept my BTC in a mycelium wallet and am looking for a way to get BCH out of it. I need instructions on how it's possible, please.

Comment: I think that this article https://en.bitcoinwiki.org/wiki/Mycelium_Wallet can help you.

Answer (score 3):

I just finished following the instructions at this link 
https://steemit.com/btc/@libert/step-by-step-guide-on-claiming-bitcoincash-from-mycellium-wallet-201783t112141477z 
and it worked quite easily. Much easier than the previous comment.

On a side note Coinomi has very clear instructions that did not work for me on how to sweep your mycelium wallet into your coinomi wallet by obtaining the private keys from your mycelium addresses butt only the first private key had a tiny bit of funds in it I checked through over 1000 more private keys and could not find any other funds so that's when I went back to Google searching and searching and found the link above.

I think how it works when you're sweeping the funds I think you're actually moving them. As opposed to when you restore your mycelium wallet with the coinomi app using the 12 words You're simply gaining access to funds without actually moving them.

Comment: I tried that link's directions but nothing's showing up on the coinomi wallet after I input my master seed from the mycelium wallet.  Any suggestions?  Also tried the sweep feature but it isn't recognizing the format of the keys.

Comment: What if you have mycelium single bitcoin address. Its got a different back up and they dont give you the private key.

Answer (score 0):

mycelium by default uses the seed to generate private keys. you must have this seed of 12 words (available when creating wallet, not sure if you can get it later).

you recreate the wallet in any other wallet program supporting seeding (most of them out there), then export private keys from the new program (as far as i know mycelium does not export private keys).

once you got those private keys, before you attempt to import them into bcash supporting wallet, send all your old bitcoins to completely new address. right after that, you can continue importing those old keys into a bcash supporting wallet, but in some virtual machine or completely other computer, as the wallet software of bcash can still scan your computer and do stuff with it it (there where cases reported already about this).

in short:

```
-use the mycelium seed to recreate wallet in other wallet software
- export private keys from that new wallet
- send old btc to completely new adress
- move to another computer
- import keys into bcash wallet
```

it should be possible to import the seed directly into bcash compatible wallet without doing stuff with keys though, too. in that case you must send your old btc to completelly new adress, not the HD generated one in mycelium

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can't find the link right now but the Mycelium Team stated in an answer to one of their app reviews that they'll soon also support bitcoin cash!

Answer (score 0):

Just download [Mycelium Bitcoin Cash Module](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mycelium.module.spvbch). It'll add Bitcoin Cash sending functionality to your wallet.

> Mycelium Bitcoin Cash Module is the first module implementing the new modular architecture.
>   The module introduces limited Bitcoin Cash(BCH) accounts support which allows to discover BCH on your BTC accounts and instantly exchange it to BTC.